# VSCODE -- has anyone figured out how to stop markdown preview from jumping to top of file?

Tags: scroll, markdown, preview, visual-studio-code

When I work on documents, I like to toggle to markdown preview frequently (old habit from MS Word days) or have the preview shown in a split window. What I've found is that the preview does not track the location that is in view in the editor, so I have to scroll down **every time** I check. If working in split window mode, the preview does not keep up and thus I have to keep scrolling that to catch up. This makes what should be an amazing workflow a bit of an irritation and it gets old very quickly.

I am considering switching editors because of it. But before I do that, I am hoping that perhaps someone out there knows of a way to pin the markdown preview to the current file location (locked scrolling, plugin, etc.) Thanks!

*** EDIT:

Ended up not switching, but found a plugin called Instant Markdown that launches a web preview of your document and renders it in real time. While it too does not track location through auto-scroll, it is much more pleasant to work with I have found, since I can move it around, even on another monitor and can thus keep much more of the render in view at once. This is a partial answer to the issue and I am no longer actively seeking the auto-scroll technique since I much prefer this technique for WYSIWYG.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this, but for VSCode.
https://atom.io/packages/markdown-scroll-sync

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to this [issue #5047](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5047), the feature you are requesting is still under development

In case you didn't switch editors yet, this feature milestone is set to January 2017, i.e. we can hope that it will be done soon